# .net c# asp.net make part of Textbox text bold

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a .NET C#/Aspx web application in which users fill in fields and the resulting form is emailed out. I have a requirement to allow users to highlight text and then make that text either bold or coloured or both.

I have done a bit of searching on the net and found that javascript might be the best option. However, when the script inserts the html tags -  it doesn't render within the textbox.I know this is a limitation of the asp.net textbox but is there anyway around this?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function formatText(tag) {
    var selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;

    if (selectedText != "") {
        var newText = "<" + tag + ">" + selectedText + "</" + tag + ">";
        document.selection.createRange().text = newText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need the text to be bold immediately? Or are you okay with adding literal text like `<b>` to the textbox, and allowing it to be passed to the email?

Comment: I need it bold immeadiately (within the asp.net textbox) - I already have it inserting the bold tags before and after the highlighted text

Answer (score 7):

You'll need a rich text editor like [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Comment: how can we implement this editor in c# ? Can you give an example.

Comment: CKEditor is completely made in JavaScript, and has a ready made ASP.NET control. http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Integration_Advanced

Answer (score 3):

Instead reinventing the wheel, take a look at a rich text editor, like for example [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) you can strip it down, so the user only have the options like bold or italic.

More info how to create a simple example can be found here:

[Create a very simple TinyMCE wysiwyg Editor](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/%22For_Dummies%22)

Comment: I should explain a bit more - the form contains hundreds of textboxes that the user enters serial numbers into. Therefore, I don't have room for each to have an individual edit panel. I also use TextBox functions such as TextBox .Replace, .Text, .BorderColor, .BackColor, .Height, .ReadOnly. Is there any way of displaying html within a aspx textbox? Something like server.htmlencode?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done in a Textbox.Go for any RichTextEditor. (CKEDITOR or CLEEDITOR)